# Pass data in other activity

Tags: java, android, database, android-intent

I have to pass my value from one activity to other one.
I download data from database with Json and it works propelly.

My First Activity:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Context context;
List<cources> valueList;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
public ListAdapter(List<cources> listValue, Context context) 
{
    this.context = context;
    this.valueList = listValue;
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return this.valueList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return this.valueList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewItem viewItem = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
         viewItem = new ViewItem();
        LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_view_test, null);

        viewItem.txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_prodotto);
        viewItem.txtDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.descrizione_prodotto);
        viewItem.txtPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prezzo);
        convertView.setTag(viewItem);
    }
    else
    {
        viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewItem.txtPrice.setText(valueList.get(position).prezzo_prodotto);
    viewItem.txtTitle.setText(valueList.get(position).nome_prodotto);
    viewItem.txtDescription.setText(valueList.get(position).descrizione_prodotto);


    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Get the position
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Dettaglio_Prodotto.class);
            // Pass all data country
            intent.putExtra("nome_prodotto", "test");

            // Start SingleItemView Class
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

}

 class ViewItem
 {
TextView txtTitle;
TextView txtDescription;
TextView txtPrice;
 }
```

I have to pass the value of:

```
viewItem.txtPrice.setText(valueList.get(position).prezzo_prodotto);
```

My Second Activity i have the code:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    nome_prodotto = i.getStringExtra("nome_prodotto");
```

How i can do it? 
if i put:

```
intent.putExtra("nome_prodotto",viewItem.txtTitle.setText(valueList.get(position).nome_prodo‌​tto));
```

i have the error: 
    Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: if i put: 
intent.putExtra("nome_prodotto", viewItem.txtTitle.setText(valueList.get(position).nome_prodotto));
i have the error:
Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final
@litelite

Comment: Do as the error says. mark the variable as final. From what i can see it's `viewItem` that must be final

Comment: @litelite `viewItem` can't be set final. It is assigned based on `convertView`'s null condition

Comment: @cricket_007 then he will have to refactor

Comment: Where i have to make final?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccon Are you sure that is the error that you get? That line shouldn't compile. `viewItem.txtTitle.setText` is a void method, so you can't pass it to `putExtra`

Comment: @cricket_007 and how i can pass it to PutExtra? thanks

Comment: You just pass `valueList.get(position).nome_prodo‌​tto`...

Comment: @cricket_007 i have the error: Variable "position" is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final – Alessandro Ceccon 4 secs ago   edit

Comment: And did you try to mark it as `final int position`?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Use an `ArrayAdapter` rather than `BaseAdapter` if you are using `List` data anyway.

As the IDE indicates, make a final variable.

```
...

else
{
    viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
}

// This is the item in the current position
final cources item = (cources) getItem(position);
```

Then, you can use that instead of repeatedly calling `valueList.get(position)`

```
viewItem.txtPrice.setText(item.prezzo_prodotto);
viewItem.txtTitle.setText(item.nome_prodotto);
viewItem.txtDescription.setText(item.descrizione_prodotto);


convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // Get the position
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Dettaglio_Prodotto.class);
        // Pass all data country
        intent.putExtra("nome_prodo‌​tto", item.nome_prodo‌​tto);

        // Start SingleItemView Class
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: Where i have to put final cources item = getItem(position);?

Comment: Just as I did in my answer. Directly above `viewItem.txtPrice.setText`

Answer (score 0):

When you use valueList in a method that creates a new onTouchListener for an instance, that is an inner class.

Any variables accessed by that class has to be final or declared inside the class. Meanign if you create a new int inside the inner class, that doesn
t have to be final. But if the int is declared outside, it has to be final.

In your case, the variable `position` has to be marked as final

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're trying to do something like this

```
intent.putExtra("nome_prodotto", valueList.get(position).prezzo_prodotto);
```

The method putExtra expects a key (String) and a value (in your case you're passing a string value).

Comment: i have the error: Variable "position" is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final